# JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I can't call my JavaScript using a freetextbox in asp.net.

Here's code my in JavaScript:

```
function validateFreetextbox()

{

    if(document.FTB_API["txt_Decs"].GetHtml == ''  )   

     {
        alert("Please Fill up desciption.");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My code's in asp.net for button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_Add" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Add_Click" Text="Add" 

Width="231px" Font-Size="11px" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="#333333"  

onclientclick=" validateFreetextbox()" />
```

Comment: I think the problem is here  if(document.FTB_API["txt_Decs"].GetHtml == ''  )

Comment: Can you show your complete code, I doubt you have different problem

Comment: @muhammad, i already put alert in the function start.

Comment: are you getting alert, if you put in the start of the funtion ?

Comment: I have edit my answer, check and let me know your findings.

Comment: @SolverFang; what are you doing, you just copy our answers and accepted the copied answer and upvote. This is wrong. Revert this back to all answers, otherwise you will be panelized about this activity. This is total unethical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should be  `onclientclick="validateFreetextbox();"`

**Edit:** for your help, I have just created page at my end try and its working... can you make new page and check this at your end...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function validateFreetextbox()
{
alert('Called');
//    if(document.FTB_API["txt_Decs"].GetHtml == ''  )   
//    {
//        alert("Please Fill up desciption.");
//        return false;
//    }
//    else
//    {
//        return true;
//    }

}

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btn_Add" runat="server"  Text="Add" Width="231px"
                Font-Size="11px" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="#333333" OnClientClick="validateFreetextbox()" OnClick="btn_Add_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you put alert in the start of the function, then you will know whether function is called or not

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar, i did, but nothing is change.

Comment: @Furqan, doesnt show anything.. it's directly saving in my database with empty value.

Comment: @SilverFang : try this, onClientClick="javascript:validateFreetextbox();"

Comment: @Furqan, its not working. i tried try it in vb.net its working using validateFreetextbox() but when i tried in C# it's not working..

Comment: @Muhammad Margaret copy/paste your code to just accepted and get the votes. Can you do something about and report it ? I think that margaret and silverfang is the same person. If you check Margaret have accepted all question by the same person only, and just copy paste our code. Did the same on me. Please check it out.

Comment: yah you are right. he just copy question some time ago, about an hour and do the same for all question. Strange... Let me do something or I will email tonight to StackOverFlow.com