# OnClient Click javascript using Freetextbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

My javascript doesnt detect my function using Freetextbox..

here's my code in javascript:
I don't know if is the right code for Freetextbox.

```
function validateFreetextbox()
{

    if(document.FTB_API["txt_Decs"].GetHtml == ''  )   
    {
        alert("Please Fill up desciption.");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

here's the code in my asp.net/C# button.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btn_Add" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Add_Click" Text="Add" 

 Width="231px" Font-Size="11px" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="#333333"  

 onclientclick=" validateFreetextbox()" />
```

Comment: Don't forget that JavaScript is not C# and [brace placement matters](http://encosia.com/2011/03/21/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/)

Comment: In C# brace placement is a matter of style, but in JavaScript is is important to end your function/if statement with a brace, otherwise JavaScript will do it for you, potentially changing the meaning of your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495662/javascript-function)

Comment: @Muhammad, i only tested only one js function there is no possible of duplication..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclientclick=" validateFreetextbox()" />` should be  `OnClientClick="return validateFreetextbox()" />`

Comment: is the function validateFreetextbox being called?

Comment: i tried to put a alert in the start of my function if it's working. And nothing's is happen.. I think my problem is in the asp button?